# Is it possible that new events are going on and will be added in next scriptures

Tags: vishnu, vedas, shiva

Pardon me if this question does not comply with the forum rules.

Some stories/events like Ramayana and Mahabharata took place on earth but others related to non-worldly deities like Shiva, Karthikeya, Ganesha took place in Kailash.

Similarly, some events like the birth of Saraswati, the curse of Jaya-Vijaya at Vishnu's place may happen in space or some other place.

Since these events didn't take place on earth, is it likely that the planning of new avatars is taking place right now?

So is it possible that the events that took place after the books were written, and those that are happening currently will be in the next version of Vedas, Upanishads and Puranas?

Some say that, in Kaliyuga, probably no one is capable of getting that information. But in the next yugas some Rishi's or Veda Vyas may get that information and add it to the scriptures?

Or are these events unlikely to happen because the whole Kalpa which is repeating is already compiled in to the currently available scriptures and just the number will change in the next set of scriptures.

Comment: can you comment why negative vote, if it is against the rule i will delete question ?

Comment: There is no 'next' version of the vedas. The vedas are the same forever.

Comment: yes anything is possible :). What is accepted as scripture and what isnt is constantly changing. While everyone agrees that Vedas, Puranas, Brahma Sutras, Upanishads, etc are classified as scriptures, there are many lesser known texts which are accepted as scriptures by various sects. So in case someone were to add new events of the latest saints, it is likely to become a scripture for those sects which follow those saints. All the best.

Comment: Yes, We are friendly with nature, friendly with animal and treated them god because they are very useful but nowadays, many people take benefit and we are making god to anyone. nowadays thousand of so called saints was/are in india and all are god for those follow them. while it is also true that saint is not defined in any scriptures and that world come from Kaliyugy babas. In scriptures, world is Rishi. So it's up to you friend, In which, you will believe because hindu dharma give full freedom to think and create your own views.

Comment: And for your Question, I think, scriptures are well defined before thousands of years ago and they do not requires any changes and addition but yes, as per scriptures, we have another avatar in  Kaliyuga, named as Kalki and we are waiting for him and Only he will have right to add new scriptures (not edit) in exist ones and he also need to follow existing scriptures which i believe.